# Implementation of Kong Api Gateway in production

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kong, konga

I want to implement Kong Api Gateway in GKE with Konga, the question I have is the following: To do it, do I necessarily have to have the external database? Or in production I can also have the database in pods....... if so, what measures should I take into account to secure the information within the Postgres implemented in the pod?

I appreciate your answers for those who want to help me solve these doubts. Greetings

I already in development did all the implementation of Kong in the pods with Konga and it works well, what I want to make sure is that it is a good choice to implement it like this in production.

Comment: Depending on what plugins you need, you may not even need a database.

Comment: Looks like you are on GCP, if you need a DB, use a managed service

Answer (score 0):

You can go with **DB-less** option, it's it will store the data in **YAML** or **JSON** file when running **Kong** **gateway** without DB.

Although i don't remember **Konga** uses anything as **DB** or not, as it has **Login** and provides **UI** for **Kong**.

There won't be any issue with **DB-less** i too had experience running with **DB** only however do check how it manage the multiple PODs config when you scale it.